# PrintArea Jquery Plugin only prints what is visible in the div

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, printing

I'm using jquery.printArea.js to print the contents of a div. The mode option is set to 'iFrame'. The div has overflow-y set so that the user can scroll vertically. When I set the print area to the div and print, it does not print everything in the div. It only prints what is displayed on the screen. How can I get the plugin to print the entire contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try on your div

```
<div style="overflow: overflow-y; height:..." class="expand-div">
....
</div>
```

And in css

```
@media print {        
   .expand-div{
        overflow: visible !important;
        height: auto !important;
   }
}
```

That should do the work!

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me!
I used CSS to limit the height of the `DIV` originally, and then the code in the answer by Silvio N:

```
#dvDetalle {
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```